# Detect the two most frequent labels in the labels variable, the other records of the dataset will be eliminated

Tags: python

I am working with a data set, from which I need to remove some records from a variable.
The datasets a is from the sklearn library:

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_kddcup99

[image]

Detect the two most frequent labels in the labels variable, the other records of the dataset will be eliminated.

[image]

datos = pd_data.groupby('labels').size().sort_values(ascending=False)
top = datos.head(2)
print(top)

[image]

I try to delete them this way but I can't delete them:

[image]

When looking at the dataset the other records still follow:

[image]

And I need:

[image]

Comment: Please use the code block instead of images or plain text.
Please refer to this page on how to ask questions [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to create a dataframe containing only those records containing the two most frequent labels.

Assuming you have a list of the desired labels a you can filter the dataframe as follows:

```
a = ["b'neptune,'", "b'normal,'"]
dfout = df['labels].isin(a)
```